# spring webflux - how to get all data from the database with an interval of 1 second?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Tell me please.

I have 4 records in my MongoDB. Okay.
I'm using Reactive Spring for current task.

If I get this request, i will get all data (4 records) from my DB:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/stream/positions", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Position> streamAllPositions() {
    return positionRepository.findAll();
}
```

I want to specify an interval of 1 second with which I will receive all records from the database (4 records in 4 seconds).
Those. I will receive the first record from the database, in a second I will receive the second record from the database, in a second I will receive the third record from the database and in another second I will receive the fourth record from the database.

I tried to do this on the basis of some default value that is generated once per second. It works fine.

```
// Get default value every 1 second
@GetMapping(value = "/stream/persons", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Person> emitPersons() {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .map(val -> new Person( 1, Sex.MAN, "default", "default", 30, "default"));
}
```

But I need to get real data from my database (not all at once, and each record separately with an interval of 1 second).

Tell me, how can I implement this?
Thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`delayElements`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#delayElements-java.time.Duration-) operator:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/stream/positions", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Position> streamAllPositions() {
    return positionRepository.findAll().delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
}
```

Comment: Сould you tell me articles or links for studying all interesting methods? Thanks

Comment: I'm glad, I could help :) Here is a useful summary about the available operators: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which-operator And the ultimate source is the actual API docs: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html

Comment: @MartinTarjányi `delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)` only delays the output for 1 second but doesn't returns reponse every 1 second

Answer (score 1):

Try adding timeouts during the retrieval.

Refer: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/